Updating MStest latest Build Error:- Constructor on type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.UnitTestRunner' not found
I am updating nuget packages for my solution so when updated
MSTest.TestAdapter.2.2.10 -> MSTest.TestAdapter.3.6.3
MSTest.TestFramework.2.2.10 -> MSTest.TestFramework.3.6.3
Locally things looking fine on visual studio what failing in build pipeline (Azure Pipline )
With below error
##[error]An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Constructor on type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.UnitTestRunner' not found.

steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*Tests.dll
     !**\obj\**
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory!=IgnoreOnBuild'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
  continueOnError: false

It should pass successfully
